# Is the "heat or UV" necessary for PVC10 + Cl => CPVC10 catalytic or endothermic and if endothermic how much energy?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, polymers, heat, catalysis

Production of Chlorinated PolyVinyl Chloride (CPVC) from PVC and chlorine requires incorporating about one part chlorine in 10 PCV to achieve around 63% chlorine mass CPVC.  This reaction is ["initiated" (according to the Plastic Pipe Institute) with UV](https://www.plasticpipe.org/PowerCommunications/BuildingConstruction/CPVC.aspx) and, [according to Wikipedia "thermal *or* UV"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorinated_polyvinyl_chloride#Production_process).  However, I have not located a source that says whether this energy is catalytic or endothermic and if endothermic, how much energy is required.

Comment: It is catalytic, as you only need to break the first chlorine-chlorine bond and then, the entire reaction is a chain reaction.